# regular expression validator in vb.net/asp.net custom expressions

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I want to make sure using the custom expression validator that no ' or " can be used i tryed using [^"'] but whenever i put normal letters it doesnt work either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do a regex replace to match ['"] and replace it with nothing (ie. "").

In VB.NET, the code would look like:

```
dim strTest as string = "This "is" a test'"
dim regex as regex = new regex("[" & chr(34) & "']", regexoptions.ingorePatternWhitespace)
msgbox(regex.Replace(strTest, ""))
```

The output will be ***This is a test***.

Comment: could u explain how to do this

Comment: its not that i dont want no text its that i do not want the actual character ' or "

Comment: chr(34) is gives you a double quote since it's ASCII character code is the decimal number 34.

Comment: Also, to make this work, you'll need "Imports System.Text.ReqularExpressions"

Comment: so i would have to do this for each field in the form?

Comment: Yes.  You would just use the regex.Replace(formField, "") when passing the data on to the next phase of your code.  If you want more info on using regex in .net, this is a great site: http://www.regular-expressions.info/dotnet.html

Comment: If you are doing this to sanitize database inputs, this really isn't good enough. It will fix some of your immediate problems, but not if [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/) comes knocking. (Google "SQL injection attack" if you're not sure what I'm talking about.) You should be using SqlCommand/OleDbCommand objects of ADO.NET.

Comment: ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.\-_]{1-100}$">

how come this isnt working in the RegularExpressionValidator

Comment: it doesnt allow normal text to be entered like a name chris

Comment: If you only want to allow alphanumeric input, replace anything that matches this: [^a-zA-Z0-9 \.\-] with nothing ("").  The "^" inside the brackets means match anything but what ever follows.  A "^" outside of the brackets means only match if it's the beginning of the string.

Comment: Also, you don't need the {1-100} because the expression inside the [] will match on a character by character basis.